# multiple initializers in Swift

Tags: swift, class, init

```
Error: play.playground:34:5: error: invalid redeclaration of 'init'
```

How do I have multiple initializers for a class in Swift? I thought that if I gave different parameters for each init, then each init would have a different method signature, and I could create multiple of them. Why doesn't this work, or have I made a mistake somewhere else? (Below is pulled from playground.)

```
//make a class
class Human{
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    init(_ name: String){
        self.name = name
        self.age = -1
    } 
    init(name: String, age: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    }
}

var newHuman = Human("bob")
print(newHuman.name)

var newHuman2 = Human(name: "Marmelade", age: 19)
print(newHuman2)
```

Comment: Your code works without any error when copied and pasted into an Xcode 9.4 Swift playground.

Comment: Note that an interesting way to do so, would be to do `init(name: String, age: Int = -1)` do pass into the same methods and avoid redundancy. That's not answering your question though. See the part "Default Parameter Values" in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

Comment: Cool, I don't know what the deal was--I just did the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: @Larme yes, good point, and will do!

Comment: @MariaTeleki don't use -1. Make the property optional and set it to nil instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass more parameters with default value like **gender: String = ""**

```
init(name: String, age: Int = 0, gender: String = ""){
    self.name = name
    self.age = age

}

var newHuman = Human("bob")
print(newHuman.name)

var newHuman2 = Human(name: "lol", age: 0)
print(newHuman2)

var newHuman3 = Human(name: "lol", age: 3, gender: "Male")
print(newHuman2)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `convenience` keyword?

```
//make a class
class Human{
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    convenience init(_ name: String){
        self.init(name: name, age: -1)
    }
    init(name: String, age: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    }
}

var newHuman = Human("bob")
print(newHuman.name)

var newHuman2 = Human(name: "Marmelade", age: 19)
print(newHuman2)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
class Your_ViewController : UIViewController {

    var yourFirstProperty : String?
    var yourSecondProperty : String?

    init(yourFirstProperty: String) {
        self.yourFirstProperty = yourFirstProperty
        self.yourSecondProperty = nil
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    init(yourSecondProperty: String) {
        self.yourSecondProperty = yourSecondProperty
        self.yourFirstProperty = nil
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) is not supported")
    }
}
```

You can easily have multiple initializers for your view controller here I have written a view controller that can be initialized in two ways and

> this is for programmers who make UI with pure code